# How can I Hyperlink a specific word at once, I don't want it hyperlink it one by one

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

How can I **hyperlink** a specific word in multiple pages of single website at once.

**Detail**
For example I have a website named word.com and there are 100 pages on this website. Now I have the word **Dog** 100 times on these 100 pages. And I want to hyperlink the word Dog with a detailed Wikipedia page.

How can I do it in HTML and CSS?

I don't know much about coding.

Comment: Read into regex

Comment: This is not a job for html or css. Write a script/program to do it. Or, `sed` may be good enough (but not html aware, so may break on some words such as `img`, or `input`.

Comment: Not possible with CSS. You need javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with only HTML and CSS. You need to write a script which reads the text containing the word "dog" and then puts an anchor `<a>` tag around it with the correct `href`. I recommend using JavaScript for this, since it is relatively easy to read from HTML elements with JavaScript.

The following code turns every occurence of dog in the element with the id `here-be-dogs` into a link, even if its in another word.

```js
const dogContainer = document.getElementById("here-be-dogs")
dogContainer.innerHTML = dogContainer.innerHTML.replaceAll(/Dog/gi, "<a href=\"test.com\">$&</a>")
```

```html
<div id="here-be-dogs">
  <p>The dog says bork!</p>
  <p>Hello, doggy!</p>
  <p>Dog dog dog dog</p>
  <p>This big dog eats hotdogs</p>
  <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
</div>
```

The regex `/Dog/gi` matches every occurence of "dog", case-insensitively.

The `$&` inside the replacement string is the matched text. I use this to preserve the casing.